# How to diagnose/stop gdm-x-session spamming syslog

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gdm, macbook-pro, syslog

[Note: this is similar to [issue #418 in the gnome gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/418) but it happens to me constantly and I'm not running Evolution.  I filed this [there too](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/612#note_863787), but gnome 3.28.2 is no longer supported there.]

I'm not sure how long this has been going on or what triggered it, but I recently noticed that my syslog is being spammed with the same 3 lines repeatedly.  For example:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "APP", prod id 41006
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "2880x1800"x0.0  337.75  2880 2928 2960 3040  1800 1803 1809 1852 +hsync -vsync (111.1 kHz eP)
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "APP", prod id 41006
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "2880x1800"x0.0  337.75  2880 2928 2960 3040  1800 1803 1809 1852 +hsync -vsync (111.1 kHz eP)
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "APP", prod id 41006
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "2880x1800"x0.0  337.75  2880 2928 2960 3040  1800 1803 1809 1852 +hsync -vsync (111.1 kHz eP)
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "APP", prod id 41006
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jul 10 04:35:53 496-MBP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2094]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "2880x1800"x0.0  337.75  2880 2928 2960 3040  1800 1803 1809 1852 +hsync -vsync (111.1 kHz eP)
```

etc. (at least 8 times per second)

I'm trying to figure out (and fix) what's causing this.  I'd appreciate any tips/pointers as to how to diagnose this.

I'm running Ubuntu on an older (2015-ish) MacBook Pro with Gnome 3.28.2 (and all apt-installed sw up-to-date):

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ apt-cache policy gdm3
gdm3:
  Installed: 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
  Candidate: 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.28.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

```
$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg
xserver-xorg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
  Version table:
     1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.7+19ubuntu7 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux 496-MBP 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ inxi
CPU~Quad core Intel Core i7-4980HQ (-MT-MCP-) speed/max~798/4000 MHz Kernel~5.3.0-62-generic x86_64 Up~51 min Mem~2430.2/15889.5MB HDD~1000.6GB(35.4% used) Procs~337 Client~Shell inxi~2.3.56
```

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   2880x1800     59.99*+
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     59.95  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     59.95  
   1440x900      59.99  
   1280x960      59.99  
   1280x854      59.95  
   1280x800      59.96  
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] [1002:6821] (rev 83)
```

Please let me know if there's other information that could help with a diagnosis.

Thanks!

Comment: A possible clue: I don't get this spam continuously.  But I *do* get two rounds of the spam whenever I run any java program using the `java` executable from openjdk11 and it opens a window (also, the window opening takes several seconds).   Running the same program in exactly the same way with the java from openjdk8 instead of 11 opens the window quickly, and does not spam syslog.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on 22.04. I passed one hour to find a way to stop the spamming. Not easy.
For your info, in my case, plugin an external HDMI is minimum one minute waiting of precious time.
**Then I expressed the problem differently.**
To stop the spamming you have to direct xorg to use the correct resolution without having to 'try' all the intermediate ones.
How ?

1. xrandr to find the desired resolution and the name

   rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~$ xrandr
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
   eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900      60.02 +
   ...
   360x202       60.02
   320x180       60.02
   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1600x900      60.00
   ...
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
   DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
2. creation of xorg.conf (not existing by default)
   rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "HDMI-2"
   Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
   EndSection
   Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "eDP-1"
   Option "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
   EndSection
   I force a lower resolution (I am old) on the laptop display.
3. Reboot your system

Et voilà. Now when I plug the external or unplug it, I only wait a few seconds.
Hope it helps.

PS : some spamming still happening but you don't wait...