# gdm-x-session syslog spam

Tags: 22.04, xorg, gdm, syslog

We upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from 16.04 sometime ago, ever since upgrading, I noticed a peculiar issue. Our `syslog` is completely spammed every second or so, by `gdm-x-session` with the following *repeating* entries:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "PHL", prod id 49343
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: 720x480 Warning: We only handle separate sync.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  108.00  1600 1624 1704 1800  900 901 904 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz eP)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1030]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
```

I couldn't find much information about this online.
I have found several users, with similar issues

1. [How to diagnose/stop gdm-x-session spamming syslog](https://askubuntu.com/q/1258011/1598316)
2. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/418

Any help is greatly appreciated

Update/edit1:

After some more research, I discovered that `gdm-x-session` is just a "wrapper" around `Xorg`.

In my case, `gdm-x-session` launches `Xorg` with the following arguments
(Copied from `/proc/#/cmdline`)

`/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolistentcp -backgroundnone -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3`

Specifically `-verbose 3` seems *interesting*, however I cannot find how to set log-verbosity from `gdm-x-session`

Update/edit2:

I discovered that you can [filter certain messages](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1162/how-to-ignore-discard-certain-syslog-messages-rsyslogd-filters) from being output to syslog.
Since `gdm-x-session` info-logs, usually start with "(II) modeset(0):"
I created the following filter in `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-gdm-x-session-filter.conf`

`:msg, contains, "(II) modeset(0):" stop`

This will discard *any* log entry with the string "(II) modeset(0):" (I couldn't get `programname` to work, for some reason).

The issue is somewhat "solved", but `gdm-x-session` still outputs device-info logs every second to `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`